# Where to add new .h and .cpp file in STM32CubeIDE project

Tags: stm32cubeide

I used STM32CubeIDE to create a new (C++) project for my nucleo-f411re board by File > New > STM32 Project. The project was created as usual. I renamed "main.c" to "main.cpp" since I selected C++ as the target language. A simple "blinky" compiles and runs correctly on the board. So now I want to begin adding some C++ code to the project.

The "main.cpp" is in the project tree under myproject > Core > Src > main.cpp. If I want to  create some new source/header files, say "foo.h" and "foo.cpp", I think I can right-click on something in the project tree, then New > Header File or New > Source File. **But the question is -- what do I right-click on to create the source/header file?** I assume the file will be created in the location (= folder) I right-click on. **Where do I want to put them?** Both of them in the "Core" folder? Separately in "Core > Inc" and "Core > Src" folders? I'm not sure.

**Edit:** I added the header/source files to Core > Inc and Core > Src respectively, and that seems to work. Is that recommended? I wonder if they will still be there if I change the configuration, causing the code to be regenerated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is a very late answer but I didn't find a lot of tips regarding this question a while ago so here is my take on it.

Basically you can place source file in any source folder.
You can use existing folders or create a new one, however you like.

Header files have to be placed inside a folder that is in the include path (e.g. `Core/Inc`) or you have to tell the compiler that a specific file should be included.
If you want to create a new folder for your header files you have to add the folder or files inside this folder to the include path via `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Setting (tab) -> MCU GCC Compiler or MCU G++ Compiler -> Include paths`.
Note that you might have to add it twice, once for C files (`MCU GCC Compiler`) and once for C++ files (`MCU G++ Compiler`).

To create a file you can simply click on the folder you want to create it in and add a new <whatever>file.
You can also just create files and directories on your local filesystem and refresh the project (right click -> Refresh or F5) to show changes in STM32CubeIDE.

---

For small projects (like a blinky project) it is probably enough to just use the `Core` folder.

For bigger projects I personally like to seperate all the autogenerated code from my own files.
Especially for C++ projects it can become very annoying that STM32CubeIDE always renames `main.cpp` to `main.c` and deletes code segments you accidentally put outside their comment blocks every time you run the code generation.

I usually create a `Project` source folder for project specific files and a `Lib` source folder for libraries.
Then I create a `cppmain.h` file that simply declares a `void cppMain()` function and a `cppmain.cpp` file that I use to write my main program.
The only change to the autogenerated code is that you have to include `cppmain.h` and call `cppMain()` before the main loop in `main.c`.

Directory tree:

```
Project name
+ Core
| + ...
+ Drivers
| + ...
+ Libs
| + someLib
| | + Inc
| | | + someLib.h or hpp
| | + Src
| |   + someLib.c or cpp
| + ...
+ Program
| + Inc
| | + cppmain.h
| | + ...
| + Src
|   + cppmain.cpp
|   + ...
+ ...
```

You will have to add `Program/Inc` and any `Lib/Inc` folder to the include path.
The changes to `main.c` then look like this:

```c
...

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "cppmain.h"  // this goes in user includes
/* USER CODE END Includes */

...

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  cppMain();  // this goes before the main loop
  // anything after this point will never be reaced
  // when you create a main loop inside cppMain()
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }

...
```

Inside the `cppmain.h` file I usually `#include "main.h"` to get all the STM32 HAL stuff and declare all hardware resource handles as extern (e.g. `extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;`)

The full `cppmain.h` file:

```c
/** @file cppmain.h
 *
 * @author some_author
 * @date some_date
 */

#ifndef PROGRAM_INC_CPPMAIN_H_
#define PROGRAM_INC_CPPMAIN_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif

#include "main.h"

void cppMain(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* PROGRAM_INC_CPPMAIN_H_ */
```

Some random `cppmain.cpp` file:

```cpp
/** @file cppmain.cpp
 *
 * @author some_author
 * @date some_date
 */

#include "cppmain.h"
#include "pins.h"
// pins is useful when you connect some things to a dev board
// and want to have a quick reference where you put stuff
// this just includes things like (for STM32F103xB "blue pill" in this case)
// #define LED_PIN_PORT GPIOC
// #define LED_PIN_PIN GPIO_PIN_13
// #define LED_PIN LED_PIN_PORT, LED_PIN_PIN


extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

int some_variable = 0;


void foo(int input){
  // do something
}


void cppMain(){
  // do stuff

  // main loop
  while(1){
    // do stuff regularly
  }
}
```

In my `Lib` folder I usually link to libraries I want to change for all projects while working on them: `right click on Libs -> New -> Folder -> Advanced >> -> Link to alternate location`.
Note that this will link to an absolute path on your system and you can't simply import your project on a different system this way.
If you work in a team or across different devices you might want to solve this a different way.

Comment: This is helpful, but somewhat confusing. Based on the dir tree, I think you meant to say "Program" instead of "Project" in "I usually create a Project source folder for project specific files and a Lib source folder ...". And, as a newbie it's useful for me to know that "source folder" is a special kind of new item. I created a dir for source so I considered it a source folder, but have to choose the item "Source Folder" in the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I am using STM32CubeIDE version 1.8, it can let you add include folder directly from the project menu -> Add/remove include path:

[image]

To add source folder, you can create source folder from the project menu -> New -> Source Folder:

[image]

If you want to add include and source folders manually:

Project Properties-> C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols:

Select `Includes` tab to add header folder

Select `Source Location` to add source folder